# How to get more than one element matched elements from a mongo array structured record

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb 2.4.6 version .
I have the following record in one of my collection named "mycollection"

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("524d3eb224bfcc31614ec8ef"),
        "symbol" : "JACK",
        "option_exp" : [
                {
                        "dateexpiration" : "2014-03-22",
                        "total_strikes" : 18,
                        "options" : [
                                {
                                        "pricevalue" : "22.5",
                                        "premium" : "100"
                                },
                                {
                                        "pricevalue" : "60.0",
                                        "premium" : "100"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "dateexpiration" : "2014-03-22",
                        "total_strikes" : 30,
                        "options" : [
                                {
                                        "pricevalue" : "122.5",
                                        "premium" : "34"
                                },
                                {
                                        "pricevalue" : "60.0",
                                        "premium" : "100"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "dateexpiration" : "2013-12-21",
                        "total_strikes" : 16,
                        "options" : [
                                {
                                        "pricevalue" : "20.0",
                                        "premium" : "100"
                                },
                                {
                                        "pricevalue" : "22.5",
                                        "premium" : "100"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to retrieve all the records belogging to a particular dateexpiration date.

I tried the below way but  its returing the whole document struture .

```
db.mycollection.find({ "symbol" : "JACK" ,"option_exp.dateexpiration" : "2014-03-22"}).pretty()
```

This below  is giving me the error  SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

```
db.mycollection.find({ "symbol" : "JACK" ,"option_exp.dateexpiration" : "2014-03-22"},{option_exp.$:1}).pretty()
```

Comment: You can return the first match or all of the document. You can't filter specific array elements currently in Mongodb. If you stored them as actual documents, this would be trivial to query.

Answer (score 1):

Try the aggregation feature, like this:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$option_exp'}, 
    {$match: {'symbol': 'JACK', 'option_exp.dateexpiration':'2014-03-22'}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/)

```
db.collection.find({ option_exp: { $elemMatch: { dateexpiration: "2014-03-22" } } });
```

Comment: Thanks for the query , when i executed the above , still i get all the data .(data belonging to different datexpirations also )